# In the distance + inversion sentence？

Tags: inversion

1. In the distance could be seen the purple mountains.
2. In the distance the purple mountains could be seen.

I know sentence 1 is right, but can you tell me whether sentence 2 is right.

Comment: Sentence 2 sounds better than sentence 1. Why do you think either one is right or that one is more right than the other?

Comment: @Mixolydian Because I saw a grammer books which says that 'In the distance' should + inverted sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither sentence is ungrammatical. Sentence 1   emphasizes the distance, and might be particularly appropriate when used to contrast with something seen close up.

> Looking out the window, the plum tree seemed to fill the yard. In the distance could be seen the purple mountains.

Sentence 2 is more neutral, in my opinion. It gives the mountains roughtly equal emphasis with the distance.

But an inverted structure is not at all required with the phrase "in the distance".

> The purple mountains were visible in the distance.

is a perfectly grammatical and normal sentence. There is nothing at all wrong with it, and indeed it sounds more usual to me than either 1 or 2 from the question.

Comment: **The purple mountains were visible in the distance.** is right, for it didn't start with the phrase **in the distance**. Is it right to say: **In the distance the purple mountains were visible.**?

Comment: " In the distance the purple mountains were visible" is perfectly acceptable, although rather less common, in my experience/